# Lifehacks is Graduating

Tags: discussion, graduation

The staff at StackExchange have tipped us the wink that Lifehacks will be one of the sites to graduate from Beta status on 16<sup>th</sup> December.

A formal announcement and details will appear on [The Main Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) in due course.

In the short term little will change, we will lose the "Beta" label.  The reputation required for privilege levels remains the same and we will not get a site-specific design.

Next year at some point there will be a Graduation Election to elect moderators for the graduated site.